# Why rand() keep giving the same value?

Tags: c++

Every time the function gets called, it's always "number = 5". The number always stays 5. I checked it already to make sure that srand is only ran once some I'm confused. This is a function inside of a class.

```
int playType::getComputerMove(){
    int number;
    if(gamesPlayed == 0){
        srand(time(NULL));
    }
    number = rand() % 1 + 5;
    return number;
}
```

Comment: `rand() % 6` would be another option

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));` should only be called once. May want to move that out of the function.

Answer (score 6):

Your issue is with the order of operations. `rand() % 1` is resolved before the adding five. Since `n % 1 = 0`, you will always get 5. Essentially, what is happening is this:

```
number = (rand() % 1) + 5;
```

In order to fix this, you will want to add parenthesis this way:

```
number = rand() % (1 + 5);
```

Comment: Good catch! I'm not sure what the OP actually wants to achieve, however - perhaps a transposition of `rand() % 5 + 1`?